# Order totals for pending payment showing total paid instead of total due

Tags: magento-1, payment, order-totals

I'm facing an issue when an order payment is not completed. On magento backend order section, order total is showing **Total Paid** amount instead of **Total Due**(as the payment is not completed)

[image: Pending payment order with total paid value]